# How to use MSER to detect regions in images

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

I have created an application that extracts the MSER data and stores it in a `CvSeq*`. I was wondering if there were any functions, or tutorials, in OpenCV that I could use to compare the data with another image using the extracted data of both images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest implementation of MSER happens to be [this](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/mser_sample.cpp?rev=2633) one using the C API. There's another listing from the Google SoC [here](http://code.google.com/p/opencv-feature-tracker/source/browse/MSER.cxx?r=e4bfa468b10c17de22785a464d8636da83b1e35a&spec=svn9427a685b9331180e64adfe1b92916b3b571a96c) using the C++ API.

I guess your best way to compare results would be to implement the code in any of the above links. Comparing the results with Matlab is generally a good thing, as we can expect that to be a standard (more or less). [VlFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/mser.html) has a library with both C and Matlab interfaces that has MSER functions. The last link also has a brief explanation from where you might be able to understand which "data" to compare. What sort of comparison do you have in mind - if it's similarity between regions in two different images, then using a Gray level Co-occurrence Matrix (GLCM) of the regions should work. The MSER will give you the regions, but comparison may not require further data of MSER.

Did you use the OpenCV `cvMSER()` function btw, or code the entire thing?

Comment: I've used OpenCV's MSER functions to extract the contour data in CvSeq* variables. Wasn't sure if OpenCV had any match functions that worked with contours.

Comment: there are, like Matching Moments etc. Also, you could get the `BoundingRect` of the CvSeq in a CvRect and then set the image ROI to that cvRect - essentially giving you the subimage corresponding to the MSER. Then the usual image matching techniques can be used (cf. above)